# How to make textfield that allows only numbers from 1 to 31 [Objective C]

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
if([newString length]>=1)
{
    NSString *sepStr=[newString substringToIndex:1];
    return !([sepStr length]>1);
}

if ([string length] == 0 && range.length > 0){
    textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    return NO;
}
NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];
if ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0)return YES;}

- (IBAction)btnc:(id)sender {

    if([_textfield.text length]>2)
    {
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING" message:@"Please Fill The Mendatory Fields." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        UIAlertAction* OK = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                             {
                             }];
        [alert addAction:OK];

    }
    else{
        desViewController *face=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"REar"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:face animated:YES];
    }
```

I have an app in which I want to enter a numeric value in `UITextField`. But I want to allow only 2 digit numbers to be entered and from 1 to 31 only . Any idea how I can modify this to accept only a numeric value limited to 2 digits and from 1 to 31 only?

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Please copy and paste your code in a code block, not linked as an image.

Comment: @KKRocks  Thanks for Editing The Post

Comment: Nobody takes `NSNumberFormatter` into account, that could do the whole work for you? Really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go
Make textfield that supports only 2 number values:

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)string
    {
      if (textField== _textfield) {
            int MAXLENGTH=2;
            NSString *newText = [_textfield.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
            if(newText.length>MAXLENGTH) {
                return NO;
            }
            return YES;
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

And for from 1 to 31 only(In Objective C) you can check a validation like this :=

```
if([_textfield.text intValue]<=31 && [_textfield.text intValue]>0)
    {
        [_textfield resignFirstResponder];
   //Your Code
    }
```

Comment: i think the condition should be [_textfield.text intValue]<=31 &&[_textfield.text intValue]>0)..am i right?

Comment: @Niharika Ya Its working Fine. Thanks for your Support. But, If i want that user can not type the third value or if user types it it will not be displayed then what to do.

Comment: Thanks for Your Support

Comment: @itsKamal this should work with first method. "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" this will not allow user to type 3 value.

Comment: @Niharika I need your help for solving a new issue . I will be very thankful to you if you help me to fix this issue . The link of my question is as follows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928852/download-files-from-bundle-on-button-click

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if(textField.text.length == 0 && [string  isEqual: @" "] )
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textField.text,string];
        NSNumber* value = nil;
        NSNumberFormatter* format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        value  = [format numberFromString:str];//returns and
        if (value == nil){
            //do something useful i.e. show alert
            return NO;
        }
        else if (value.intValue > 31)
        {
            return NO;
        }
        else
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First set keybordType to NumberPad so that your UITextField can't support anything other than numbers. Then make your UITextField listen to editing events within it.

```
[mTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
[mTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Now 'textFieldDidChange' method should be something like this. It won't take any input other than numbers within 1 to 31.

```
- (void) textFieldDidChange : (id) sender {
    NSString *text = [mTextField text];
    if (text == nil) {
        return;
    }

    int value = text.intValue ;
    if (value < 1) {
        [mTextField setText:@""];
        return;
    }

    if (value > 31) {
        NSString * val = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value];
        val = [val substringToIndex: (val.length - 1)];
        [mTextField setText:val];
    }
}
```

I hope this will definitely help.

Comment: Thanks for Your Support, But I want that when user click submit button then it would be checked, That the number is less than 31 or not. I am very thankful to Niharika for Solving the issue.

Comment: Then you should be very specific when asking a question. By the way, in my solution, you don't have to check if it's less than 31 or not. A simple nil check will be enough because you'll never have anything other than 1-31 in your uitextField if you follow my solution.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I will be More Specific Next Time.

Answer (score -1):

Keep your logic simple as clear.

Make your `textField` to only allow `Number Type` input:

```
self.yourTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

Then in `-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", textField.text, string];
    long intValue = str.integerValue;
    if (intValue < 1 || intValue > 31) {
        self.yourTextField.text = textField.text;
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Your Support, But I want that when user click submit button then it would be checked, That the number is less than 31 or not.

Comment: Well. But your question doesn’t reflect what you are trying to achieve. If so, edit your question and be specific

Comment: What, if the replacement is at the beginning of the text field?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, no logic here for the replacement. `textField.text = textField.text;` stands for filling the textField with previous value.

Comment: I'm talking about `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", textField.text, string]`. However, `textField.text = textField.text` is simply meaninglessand does exactly nothing.

Comment: It should be `yourTextField` instead of `textField`. Silly mistake